figure captions of the two subfigures to be centered, while the main caption should be justified rather than centered
I am encountering an issue when using the subcaption environment in LaTeX. I want the captions of the two subfigures to be centered, while the main caption should be justified (aligned at both ends) rather than centered. Currently, the code I am using is unable to achieve this effect.
This is my code:
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{figure*}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Fig333.png}
        \caption{Subfigure A}
        \label{fig:subfig_a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Fig444.png}
        \caption{Subfigure B}
        \label{fig:subfig_b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[Short Caption]{This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure*}



Welcome! Can you complete your code so we can compile it?

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht!]% h is turned into ht anywaymnnnnnnnnnn;;
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Fig333.png}
        \caption{Subfigure A}
        \label{fig:subfig_a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Fig444.png}
        \caption{Subfigure B}
        \label{fig:subfig_b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[Short Caption]{This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.This is the main caption that is two-line aligned. This caption is longer to show the alignment across the width of the text.}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


